# iPhone 6s Plus experiencing unexpected touch input

Tags: iphone

Recently, my iPhone 6s Plus randomly starts opening programs and games one after the other until I shut it down. Then yesterday when I was on a phone call, numbers started rolling across the top of the screen like it was trying to dial. Today, when I was on a call, it disconnected twice with the message "system failure!"

Any idea what is going on?  It is a little over a year old.

Comment: Would you be able to update your question with the iOS version and repair history of your device?

Comment: kinda sounds like something is wrong with the screen. Like it's getting ghost touch events. Are you near an Apple Store? I'd take it in there to have a pro look at it.

Comment: I am running 11.3 and have had no repairs done.

Comment: The nearest Apple retail store is about 100 miles, but it is beginning to look like that may be my best option.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to get your iPhone inspected by an Apple authorised technician. It appears there is something wrong with the hardware. It is also advisable to update to the latest version of iOS (iOS 11.3 as of this writing). You can try resetting your device (after taking a backup), and see if that resolves the problem.